# How to change visualization profiler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I need to change my hand visualization in the middle of the game, so I would like to change the visualization profile because if I try to just remove and create a new model the old one will appear again.

I don't know how to access to profiles though code so I need some help.

I'm currently using MRTK v 2.0.0 RC1-Refresh and Unity 2019.1.0f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the hand tracking profile from the MRTK instance in the scene:
`MixedRealityHandTrackingProfile profile = MixedRealityToolkit.Instance.ActiveProfile.InputSystemProfile.HandTrackingProfile;`

*However* it is not possible to change the visualizer prefabs in the profile through code, they are readonly properties. This has several reasons:

- Profiles properties are often just read once on start and effects will only show up after restarting
- Default profiles are read-only anyway and not supposed to be modified

If you want to change the hand visualization it is preferable to [disable the hand visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QANR8.png) and then replace it by attaching your own objects to the hand joints:
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/InputSystem/HandTracking.html#joint-transform-from-hand-visualizer